# my application doesnt start because of the product id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently stuck on a piece of code.  Please help guys. I am developing an online store. Everything works perfect until i add this line of code `(product_id: do product.id)`  to my homepage.  Here is the problem when i try to load the application.

```
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\COMPUTER>cd desktop

C:\Users\COMPUTER\Desktop>cd trial

C:\Users\COMPUTER\Desktop\trial>cd depot

C:\Users\COMPUTER\Desktop\trial\depot>rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
*** SIGUSR2 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGUSR1 not implemented, signal based restart unavailable!
*** SIGHUP not implemented, signal based logs reopening unavailable!
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-23 17:21:30 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
  Rendering store/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered store/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1256ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



SyntaxError (C:/Users/COMPUTER/Desktop/trial/depot/app/views/store/index.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
d to Cart' , line_items_path (product_id: product.id)  );@ou
                              ^
C:/Users/COMPUTER/Desktop/trial/depot/app/views/store/index.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
th (product_id: product.id)  );@output_buffer.safe_append='
                              ^
C:/Users/COMPUTER/Desktop/trial/depot/app/views/store/index.html.erb:24: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
          ensure
                ^):

app/views/store/index.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
app/views/store/index.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
app/views/store/index.html.erb:24: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
  Rendering C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (88.0ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (32.0ms)
  Rendering C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (9608.1ms)
```

this is the homepage.....

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p> 

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1> 
<% cache @products do %>
<% @products.each do |product| %> 
<% cache @product do %>
<div class="entry"> 


<h3><%= product.title %></h3> 

<%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
<%= sanitize(product.description) %>
<div class="price_line"> 

<span class="price"><%= number_to_currency (product.price) %></span> 

<%= button_to 'Add to Cart' , line_items_path (product_id: do product.id)  %>
</div> 
</div> 
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

this is the controller.....

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove space between `line_items_path` and its arguments (and remove this `do` keyword):

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(product_id: product.id) %>
```

Comment: Adding spaces like this leads to ambiguity which leads to bugs which leads to Stack Overflow questions which could have been avoided by keeping things orderly and well-formatted. To stomp out habits like this, tools like [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) are very good at laying down the law.